# Call didFinishPickingImage with custom camera button?

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am creating a custom camera view that I use to take a picture. Here is what I have:

```
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.25, 1.25);


// Create View
UIView *vieww = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[vieww setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[vieww setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

// Create tcustom tab bar
UIImageView *tabBarBack = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bar_back.png"]];
tabBarBack.frame = CGRectMake(0, 426, 320, 54);
[vieww addSubview:tabBarBack];

UIButton *cameraButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[cameraButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera_icon_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cameraButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera_icon_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
[cameraButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera_icon_normal_hit.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[cameraButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera_icon_normal_hit.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
cameraButton.frame = CGRectMake(114, 435, 99, 42);
[vieww addSubview:cameraButton];

UIButton *cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[cancelButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 435, 99, 42);
[vieww addSubview:cancelButton];

UIButton *uploadImageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[uploadImageButton setTitle:@"Roll" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
uploadImageButton.frame = CGRectMake(215, 435, 99, 42);
[vieww addSubview:uploadImageButton];

picker.cameraOverlayView = vieww;
```

Now how can I make `cameraButton` take the picture? with a `addTarget:action`? If so, how will it call the `didFinishPickingImage`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `UIImagePickerController`'s `takePicture`.

```
[cameraButton addTarget:picker action:@selector(takePicture) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

It will call the delegate method.

Comment: @Deepak: Thanks for your answer! However, there is no shutter and sound effect. Is there any way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: @phpnerd211 It should've it already. It does in my test app and I copied most of the code here. Except for the cancel and upload buttons.

Comment: @Deepak: It doesn't show? Tested it on my 3G. About to test it on a 3GS.

Comment: @Deepak: Reword it -- It shows up when you open the UIImagePickerControlelrSourceTypeCamera up, but not when you take the picture.

Comment: Reword what? I didn't get you.

Comment: When the UIImagePickerController comes up, the shutter shows and hides. But when I take a picture, it doesn't show up.